# When I'm saving my WPF code in Visual Studio 2015, it reformats it for each control to be on one line. How do I disable this?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So the issue I'm having is after I save my code, it reformats all controls I had stacked properties on to one line.  The first picture shows what it looks like before I save, and the second one is after I save.  I use the shortcut ctrl+s, but it still does it no matter how I save.  I've done a fair amount of research, and I've got no idea what the issue is.  Any help is appreciated!

Before I save:

[image: Before I save]

After I save:

[image: After I save]

Comment: That would be mindbogglingly annoying. Try Tools | Options > Text Editor/XAML/Formatting/Spacing

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't have any addons such as ReSharper installed, do you? This shouldn't be ReSharper's default, but addons could exhibit this behavior.

Comment: It wasn't ReSharper, but I had xaml styler, which was causing the problems.  Thanks for the idea of extensions!